# What is the right codomain for arccos(x)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A function is said to be a rule that assings a unique $f(x) \in Y$ to $\forall x \in X$.

$$f:X\to Y$$ where $X$ is domain and $Y$ is codomain.

$\arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ which is violating the definition of function as long as we take the codomain to be $[-\pi,\pi]$. What is the right codomain for $\arccos(x)$ then? $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$?

Comment: $\arccos$'s *principal range* is $[0,\pi].$

Its codomain can be $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look at the function $\cos:\mathbb R\to[-1,1]$ as it is not an injective function in all its domain we cannot look for an inverse function, so we look for an interval for which $\cos(x)$ is an injective function, then we take Domain$=[0,\pi]$. Then $\cos:[0,\pi]\to [-1,1]$ is bijective. Thus there exists an inverse function that will be denoted by $\arccos:=[-1,1]\to[0,\pi]$.

[image]

Comment: again $arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{3\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: @Orpheus I guess you meant $\cos(\pi/4)=\cos(3\pi/4)=1/\sqrt{2}$ but it's false because $\cos(3\pi/4)=-1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: you are right....but then how about sin(x) then? $sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking with the earlier comment on cosine..cos(x) is bijective in the range $[0,\pi]$

Comment: @Orpheus Following in the footsteps of my answer, you should have to $\arcsin:[-1,1]\to[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is biyective.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zaragosa

Comment: Should I delete this question?...It seems really awkward to ask a question like this now that I think of it

Comment: I do not think you should eliminate it, there must be someone who has the same doubt or question and here you can find something to guide you.

Comment: sure....@Zaragosa